Chrome extension Insecure CSP value
Insecure CSP value in chrome extension.
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "ASDF",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "ASDF",
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/slack-logo.png",
    "32": "images/slack-logo.png",
    "180": "images/slack-logo.png",
    "192": "images/slack-logo.png",
    "512": "images/slack-logo.png"
  },
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "contextMenus", "tabs", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self';"
  }
}


If i use the above content security policy, the extension build is getting loaded but while opening the extension, I'm getting error as Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-6YAOYbVm9ElCxbsfIJfzPLj4oAb9VijVytz9kOhJ/38='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "ASDF",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "ASDF",
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/slack-logo.png",
    "32": "images/slack-logo.png",
    "180": "images/slack-logo.png",
    "192": "images/slack-logo.png",
    "512": "images/slack-logo.png"
  },
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "contextMenus", "tabs", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' sha256-5F95733C4CDFE823HHB647F57E74DE2E726BBC6G2B2F7DF7AD05C5F88778ABC2; object-src 'self';"
  }
}

And If i use the above manifest.json , then while loading using load unpacked in chrome dev mode, I'm getting error as Error
'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value "sha256-5F95733C4CDFE823AAB647F57E74DE2E726BBC6A2A2F7DF7AD05C5F88778AED2" in directive 'script-src'.
Could not load manifest. Which means it's not getting loaded only
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self';",
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts allow-forms allow-popups allow-modals; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; child-src 'self';"
  }

And if i use the above then also it's not getting loaded. At the beginning itself during I load, I'm getting error as
'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value "'unsafe-inline'" in directive 'script-src'.
Could not load manifest.

The error says you have an inline JS in a script element or attribute, apparently in index.html. There's no way to allow it other than in a sandbox which is a separate page which you can add as an iframe in the action popup (index.html).

@wOxxOm
what's the solution for that? I'm using build of react(within dist folder). any solution for that? Would be appreciated. Thank You...
